# why is $6$ divided by $1245=207.5$ ?instead of $207$ remainder $3$?

Tags: divisibility

Help, $\frac{6}{1245}= 207.5$?

I did long division to get my answer.
But when I calculate it myself I end up with $207$ remainder $3$ ,how does that translate into $.5$?

Comment: Because 3/6 = 0.5?

Comment: but where are you getting 3/6 from?

Comment: That's what "remainder $3$" means.

Comment: OH Right, Stupid me, thanks

Comment: The remainder of integer division is the amount left over that you haven't divided by the divisor yet (because it is too small to be divided evenly). So to "finish" the division 1245/6 = 207 (remainder 3), divide 3 by 6 and add it to 207.

Comment: Please see Marty Cohen’s answer. In mathematics, precision is all.

Comment: In the title you write $6$ is divided by $1245$ but when you write $6/1245$ it means $1245$ is divided by $6$. When you say $b$ is divided by $a$,it means,$b$ is the [dividend](https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/dividend.html) and $a$ is the [divisor](http://www.amathsdictionaryforkids.com/qr/d/division.html).

Answer (score 4):

You say "6 divided by 1245",
but you are doing
"1245 divided by 6".